# Any libraries that can create a pop up window with a shadow?

Tags: android, popupwindow, floating-action-button, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to look for some kind of library or example code that creates a pop up window that has two buttons "Get current location" and "Google Maps". I would also want the window to appear floating for nice synthetic look. I don't need code to show me how to get current location or to make a google maps activity (I've done that already).

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 1):

Needs a background in order to drop a shadow. This (setElevation) will only work with >= 21.

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
popupWindow.setElevation(10);
```